# The use of "ciò" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, pronouns

What is the use of "ciò" in the sentence? In translation over dictionary it means "that" or "it", but as a conjunction, pronoun, or demonstrative?
Since I've seen some other words as conjunction and demonstrative in Italian, then I guess it must be pronoun, but with which usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a masculine pronoun, only singular, and it indicates or replaces the noun of a thing, generally referred as a verb or a phrase, it can be both subject and complement.

> It has neutral value and it is mostly used with the relative che *: chiedimi **ciò** che vuoi*. In the past it could refer to plural nouns and people names used in conjunction to the verb *essere* (v. *cioè*). With meaning and particular usages: *a ciò, a questo fine, a tal fine; a ciò che* (v.
>   *acciocché*); *da ciò*, appropriate, suitable to the thing or to the aim you're talking about: *Ma non eran da
>   ciò le proprie penne* (Dante); and in conjunctive expressions: *per ciò (v.
>   perciò), per ciò che (v. perciocché);* or adversative: *con tutto ciò,
>   ciò nonostante, ciò nondimeno*. ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cio/))

It can be used as *questa cosa* (this thing), *quella cosa* (that thing):

*Tutto **ciò** è vero*: that's all true.
*Parlammo a lungo di **ciò** che gli era accaduto*: we talked a lot about what happened to him.
*Hai fatto **ciò** che ho detto?*: have you done what I told you?

Comment: Is "Tutto questo/quello è vero" wrong? I can not perceive the difference between "quello" and "ciò".

Answer (score 3):

Just adding some tips about usage of **ciò**: in most of the cases you can replace **ciò** by **quello**, specially in spoken Italian:

A says something, 
B responds: Ciò è vero. Però devi tenere presente che....
(That's true. However you should also take into account...).

Non sono d'accordo con **ciò/quello** che hai appena detto
*I don't agree with what you just said*

Tutto **ciò/quello** che...
*All that...*

Tutto **ciò/quello** che so è che....
*All I know is that...*